# Does Judaism adjudicate cases involving mental anguish?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, torts-damages, psych-mentalhealth

If a non-physical act, such as exposure to viewing something which the current medical field would deem traumatizing, is intentionally perpetrated by one person on another, are there any legal ramifications?

As an example to make things more concrete (**NOTE I AM NOT ASKING ABOUT THIS SPECIFIC CASE**) If an adult were to expose a young person to graphic images of torture, would the adult be halachically culpable in any way?

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87705

Answer (score 9):

The Talmud in Bava Kama 91a talks about inducing panic in someone -- "our courts can't charge the person, but Heaven will take him to task." I would assume the same would apply here, at first glance. (I'm not well-read on the halachic literature on the subject.)

The classical examples of charging for embarrassment involve physical actions such as spitting on someone, slapping them, or pulling their pants down.