# May someone say the prayer for the ill for someone who is emotionally "ill"?

Tags: tefilla, choleh-sick, psych-mentalhealth

*Lo Aleinu*. Let's say someone's friend's teen-age daughter died from a terrible sickness. The parents have been distraught and "disabled" for year because of the emotional trauma. They isolate themselves at home for the most part, and they are unable to place a headstone on their daughter's grave because it is too painful for them.

Can one say *misheberach l'cholim* for such a situation? I'm thinking, perhaps, yes, because the end of the prayer says *refu'at hanefesh* - a healing of the spirit / soul.

Comment: Perhaps relevant is my [recent question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87705/9682) about whether psychological trauma is equivalent to physical trauma regarding payment.

Comment: I edited diabaled -> disabled assuming this is what you meant - rollback otherwise

Answer (score 7):

One is exempt (from punishment) by extinguishing a flame on Sabbath for the sake of an emotionally ill person (cf. Rambam's commentary to Mishnah Shab. 2:5). Emotional instability/numbness also renders a Kohen unfit for service in the Temple (Bech. 7:5).

From the above I believe an emotionally "disabled" person can be considered a *choleh* for who *Mi she'berach* may be recited*, as for a physically ill person.

*Besides for there being no halachic issue (AFAIK) with reciting it for such a person.